# how to redirect example.com to 127.0.0.0/main/test?

Tags: windows, wamp

i'm using wamp 5, windows XP. i have edited my host file in my local disk like the code below and it works

> 127.0.0.0  example.com

but i'd like to redirect to a particular folder, if i change it to the code below, it dont work

> 127.0.0.0/main/site  example.com

how to redirect `example.com` to `127.0.0.0/main/site` locally in my PC?

btw, i dont want to install any new software to solve this prob

Comment: You don't redirect to a particular folder using the hosts file, that is only for name resolution. Use virtual hosts in WAMP: http://blog.jbheren.com/post/2011/01/25/configure-virtual-hosts-in-wamp-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Virtual Hosts

Leave the HOST file as 
127.0.0.1  example.com

When you define a Virtual Host you also tell it which folder is its DocumentRoot so that will send it to the right place when you use the address example.com in the browser.

Check out [wampserver.com](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,113686,113701#msg-113701)